# Caixa de texto acompanhar a imagem

Tags: html, css, imagem, img, style

Fala galera, blz? minha primeira pergunta aqui k, to com uma duvida. Estou tentando fazer essa caixa de texto ficar fixa sobre determinado altura da imagem, porem, quando aumento a tela. caixa fica e a imagem vai.
por exemplo, se eu der um text-align center no container, a imagem vai porem o texto fica. alguma ideia?[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX5wj.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGmDL.png)

meu código:

```css
body{
    background-color: #000;
}

 .phone{
    position: relative; 
} main{
    align-items: center;
}
.caixa{
    background-color: black;
    width: 20em;
    height: 5em;
    border: 2px solid #404040;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 3em;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
display: flex;    
} 
.telefone > #mobile{
  max-width: 400px;

  text-align: center;
} .caixa h1{
    color: white;
}
#box{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
} #download{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Boa Noite, Tudo bem?! Coincidentemente também sou nova por aqq então se a minha pergunta nn ficar muito boa me desculpa aí, bom que crescemos juntos nessa plataforma e que tudo certo :)

Bem, vendo seu código aqq. no seu CSS tenta colocar na propriedade #box{Position:fixed;} ou na que vc queira que fique fixa por que no caso dessa propriedade o (Posicionamento fica Fixo na página, independente da barra de
rolagem.)

Espero ter ajudado <3

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta. o problema de eu usar o fixed, é que quando eu aumentar a pagina pq to fazendo responsivo ele nao esta indo junto. acabei que consegui com o position relative.